# JSFiddle code is working, static file alone is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

the following code works flawlessly up until the point where "premium and such specs" and it does not display anything. however, on this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ej4j8/3/ the code IS working properly and under the "premium specs and such" is displays zero.  (another error i need to deal with)... if someone could tell me what warppers JSfiddle is using to make this work it would be great. im at a loss as obviously is the same code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 

/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background-color:#FFC926;
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), ;
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin:10% 0% 5%  15%; 
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 10.33%;
    float:left;

    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
</style>
 </head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
function calculateTotal()
{

    var boilerPrice = getBoilerSizePrice() + getBedroomSizePrice() + getBathroomSizePrice()  + getTankSizePrice() ;

    //display the result
        var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "total price £"+boilerPrice;

    var divobj2 = document.getElementById('premPrice');
    divobj2.style.display='block';
    divobj2.innerHTML = "Premium price £"+((boilerPrice/100)*120);

}



var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})





 //Property Type array

 var house_prices = new Array();
 house_prices["Semi"]=1029;
 house_prices["Detatched"]=1290;
 house_prices["Terrace"]=1100;
 house_prices["Flat"]=900;

 function getBoilerSizePrice()
{  
    var boilerSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["msform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["house"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            boilerSizePrice = house_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return boilerSizePrice;
}




 var tank_prices = new Array();
 tank_prices["Yes"]=500;
 tank_prices["YBR"]=890;
 tank_prices["No"]=0;


 function getTankSizePrice()
{  
    var tankSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["msform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["tank"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            tankSizePrice = tank_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return tankSizePrice;
}

 //bedroom number array 

 var bedroom_prices= new Array();
 bedroom_prices["Beds1"]=89;
 bedroom_prices["Beds2"]=94;
 bedroom_prices["Beds3"]=112;
 bedroom_prices["Beds4"]=145;
 bedroom_prices["Beds5"]=169;
 bedroom_prices["Beds6"]=178;



  function getBedroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bedroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["msform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bedroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bedroomSizePrice = bedroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bedroomSizePrice;
}

  //bathroom number array
 var bathroom_prices = new Array();
 bathroom_prices["One"]=119;
 bathroom_prices["Two"]=129;
 bathroom_prices["Three"]=140;



function getBathroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bathroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["msform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bathroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bathroomSizePrice = bathroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bathroomSizePrice;
}






/* ellement for hiding classes
$(".").hide();
*/

});

</script>

<form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Getting A Quote Is Easy</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We'll give you a quote in a few easy steps</h3> <br/>
<p>Just tell us which options are most similar to your home</p>
        <br/>        

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">What Type Of Home Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <label >Type Of Property</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Semi" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Detatched" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Terrace" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="house" value="Flat" onclick="calculateTotal()" /></label><br/>
                <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bedrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <label >Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Bed1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />6</label><br/>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bathrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <label >Number of Bathrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="One" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Two" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bathroom" value="Three" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>        


    </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Do You Have A Cylinder</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

     <label >Do You Have A Cylinder Tank</label>
     <br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="Yes" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="YBR" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Yes (but needs removing)</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="tank" value="No" onclick="calculateTotal()" />No</label><br/>
                <br/>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Packages Available</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

    <p>standard and premium system specs</p>
    <br/>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                <br/>
                <div id="premPrice"></div>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Enter your details to a get a free survey</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Maybe try narrowing down the problem by reducing the amount of code.

Comment: It is a scope issue because you are defining methods inside ready handler which here is useless. Just wrap event binding in ready handler, not methods which should be on global scope. Or remove ready handler and set all your scripts before `</body>` closing tag. That's said, if you had checked your console before posting this question, you should have be able to fix it yourself

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent But e.g `calculateTotal()` is not on global scope, so `onclick="calculateTotal()"` will throw an error. EDIT: that's said, jsFiddle has same issue too

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateTotal is not defined

You're calling functions from your HTML, but they are not in the global scope.

**Example :**

```
...
<input type="button" name="house" value="Semi" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
...
```

Here you're calling `calculateTotal()`, but this function is wrapped in your `$(document).ready()` function, which mean **it can't be reached outside** this `$(document).ready()` :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    ...
    function calculateTotal() {}
    ...
}
```

To get it work, you must define this kind of functions **out of** `$(document).ready` :

```
function calculateTotal() {}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    ...
}
```